# np.random.choice error : probabilities doesn't sum to 1, but print says it does ?

Tags: python, random, sum

I'm having a small problem when using numpy's random.choice function.
I'm giving it a list (a), and the probabilities associated with this list (p) (I'm trying to generate random text, implementing a bigram markov model with probabilities calculated on a training corpus).
Problem is, it crashes mid-program, telling me that the probabilities don't sum to 1. 
Bigger problem is, sum(p) DOES sum to 1.

Is this a bug ? Does random.choice sums differently than the regular sum function ? Am I missing something ?

Here's the code:

```
def randomBigram(self):
    doc = open(self.path+"/randomGenBi.txt", "wb")
    lettre = str(np.random.choice(self.letters.index))
    a = [elem for elem in self.probaBigram.index if elem[1] == lettre]
    p = [self.probaBigram[elem] for elem in self.probaBigram.index if elem[1] == lettre]
    random = np.random.choice(a, p=p)
    i = 0
    while i < 5000:
        lettre = str(np.random.choice(self.letters.index))
        print "lettre", lettre
        a = [elem for elem in self.probaBigram.index if elem[1] == lettre]
        p = [self.probaBigram[elem] for elem in self.probaBigram.index if elem[1] == lettre]
        if sum(p) != 1.0:  #debug
            print "somme sur p:", sum(p)
            print "not equal"
        else:
            print "equals one"
        random = np.random.choice(a, p=p)
        doc.write(random)

        i += 1
```

And here's a sample of my shell output:

lettre a
sum for p: 1.0
not equal

I just don't really get it...

Any help is welcome :)

Thank you !

Jessica

Comment: what is the full traceback?

Comment: Is this just rounding error? Floating point math is rarely "equal" - more often "very close". The more terms the bigger the possible error. Is it within 1e-16 or is it way off (in other words what if you test `abs(sum-1)<1e-16`)

Comment: Could you try to reduce this to a complete and short example? What you have now does a lot more than reproduce your problem without being complete.

Comment: Full traceback:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NGrammes.py", line 283, in <module>
    ng.randomBigram()
  File "NGrammes.py", line 234, in randomBigram
    random = np.random.choice(a, p=p)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1026, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:7322)
ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1
But Tim is right, using repr did show it doesn't really sum up to 1, it just comes really close. It should be one though, that's strange...  You're probably right Floris, it might be just a rounding error, as I do have a lot of values.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
print "somme sur p:", sum(p)
```

to

```
print "somme sur p:", repr(sum(p))
                      ^^^^^      ^
```

and try again.  `print` implicitly applies `str()` to items before printing them, and in "old enough" versions of Python `str` rounds floats to 12 significant digits.  There are many floats not equal to 1 that will print as `1.0` then.  But the only float whose repr displays as `1.0` is exactly 1.0.

Once you discover that the sum really isn't 1.0, show us what it is and ask a new question about what to do next ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! Well, using repr did show that the sum wasn't exactly one, but more 1.0000000002, or 0.99999987... hmmm. So it is indeed NOT equel to one,  but it should be... could it be a float rounding problem ? Anyway, as you say I guess it's time for a new question :) I'll just double check my probabilities first to make sure I didn't mess up somewhere else... :)